# Cannot populate dropdown from Javascript Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have a dropdown which i am trying to populate from the javascript. But i am unable to do it.

This is my `HTML`

```
    <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown values">
    <input type="hidden" name="values" selectOnBlur={false}>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Select a category</div>
    <div class="menu">


    </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the `JS`

```
$('.ui.dropdown.values').dropdown({values:[{name:"oi",value:32},{name:"yo",value:2}]})
```

Please find the codepen link below
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sanjithkumar017/pen/BmXgYm)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be fixed by changing versions to:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.2.13/dist/semantic.min.js

Because the dropdown library's version you used didn't support populating via JS (as per docs)